# Set current DHCP IPv4 as static in powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to get the current IPv4 address assigned to the PC and set it to be static using a script?

The script must be able to get current active IPv4 from a wired interface and then offer an option to set it as static

If possible, please make the script to also have an option to restore to DHCP after setting it as static.

Thank You

Comment: Do not hijack IP addresses that are managed via DHCP.

Comment: Are you sure you are not kidding me? An IP address can be set statically or dynamically via DHCP, do you manually set it or do you use a script to do it is another question. I don't understand how can somebody mention hijack here. If you are a coder with no idea about networking that's a different story

Comment: What do you think will happen when the hijacked IP address is dynamically assignd to some other host by the DHCP server? Do you expect network communication to go well with an IP address conflict on the network? DHCP reservations are a slightly different story, but even then the DHCP admin could single-sidedly modify a reservation, leading to the same problem.

Comment: DHCP is smart enough to not assign IP addresses which are already assigned statically or dynamically lol

Comment: Too many business practices require the IP to be static. In that case - instead of doing an ipconfig to get the IP address and then manually go to the adapter to make changes, you simply run a script, you get it and assign it to the PC

Comment: *"DHCP is smart enough to not assign IP addresses which are already assigned statically"* Well, it appears that there *is* someone here who has [no idea](http://serverfault.com/a/570622/134295) [about networking](https://superuser.com/a/900078/156043).

Comment: ok, elaborate and bring references if you claim otherwise

Comment: I maintain that DHCP only assigns IP addresses that are not currently assigned

Comment: *"elaborate and bring references if you claim otherwise"* I already did, in case you didn't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i tried to write a nice code for you

```
#Setting up the interface t get the address from
clear-host
write-host
Write-Host "   |-------------------------------------------------|"
Write-Host "   |                                                 |"
Write-Host "   |     Welcome ... -help by Aayush Kharel          |"
Write-Host "   |                                                 |"
Write-Host "   |-------------------------------------------------|"
write-host
write-host "You have following interfaces in you computer ..."
$intalias = (get-netadapter).interfacealias
for ($i=1; $i -le $intalias.length; $i++) 
{
    $temp = $intalias.get($i-1)
    write-host "   $i. $temp "
}
write-host
$selectedinterfacenum = read-host "Select the number of the interface you want to use"
$interfacealias = $intalias.get($selectedinterfacenum - 1)
write-host
write-host " You selected $interfacealias ..."
write-host
$interface = get-netipconfiguration -interfacealias $interfacealias
#Get ipv4 address
$ipaddress = $interface.ipv4address.ipv4address
#get default gateway
$ipgateway = $interface.ipv4defaultgateway.nexthop
#to get the subnet mask we need to use wmi object
$interface2 = get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where-object {$_.defaultipgateway -ne $null}
#Getting the subnet mask
$ipsubnet = $interface2.ipsubnet | select-object -first 1
#We have to convert subnet mask to cidr notation
$mask = $ipsubnet.split(".")
$cidr = [int] 0
$octet = [int] 0
foreach ($octet in $mask) {
    if ($Octet -eq 255){$CIDR += 8}
    if ($Octet -eq 254){$CIDR += 7}
    if ($Octet -eq 252){$CIDR += 6}
    if ($Octet -eq 248){$CIDR += 5}
    if ($Octet -eq 240){$CIDR += 4}
    if ($Octet -eq 224){$CIDR += 3}
    if ($Octet -eq 192){$CIDR += 2}
    if ($Octet -eq 128){$CIDR += 1}
} #end foreach
#Output
write-host Your IPv4 Address from DHCP is 
write-host "   Address  $ipaddress"
write-host "   Subnet   $ipsubnet"
write-host "   Gateway  $ipgateway"
write-host "   CIDR     $cidr"
write-host
$answer = read-host "Do you want to set it as static ? (Y/N) "
write-host
if ($answer -eq "y") 
{
    write-host "Setting up the address to static ..."
    remove-netipaddress -interfacealias $interfacealias -addressfamily ipv4
    new-netipaddress -interfacealias $interfacealias -ipaddress $ipaddress -prefixlength $cidr -defaultgateway $ipgateway
    write-host "Your ip address is now static ..."
}
else {write-host " You choose not to set it as static ... " }

write-host #theEnd
```

Save the script as ps1 and run it
Let me know if you have any problem regarding it Thanks

Comment: Thanks Buddy, this works. You forgot the DNS which would make the internet unusable if set, but this scrip sets IP information to static. Good job

Comment: $intalias.get what is the meaning of .get? Seems like it is a method. What does it do? Can't find get when I pipe the command to gm?

Comment: it is a method 
it gets selected interface from your list of interfaces